# I would like to upgrade my Shimano disc rotors from 160mm to 203mm. How to pick the right rotors?

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake

My bicycle came with the BR-MT200 (https://www.bike-discount.de/en/buy/shimano-br-mt200-disc-brake-set-721603) brake set: hydraulic levers, 160mm rotors.

I'd like to upgrade to 203mm, but I don't know what rotor to choose. My curent ones are marked SM-RT10-8.

How do I pick compatible ones? All I know is that they are centre lock. And should I be upgrading both rear and front, or front only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To upgrade rotors you'll need to change the disc brake caliper mount adaptor too. This is specific to your fork but as you currently have 160mm disc, you'll need to an adaptor to move your caliper out for the 203mm rotor to fit. See [this post](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/66046/upgrade-160mm-to-200mm-disc-brake-rotor) for a little on that.

For what disc to get, it all depends on how much money you want to spend. If you're just using the bike for commuting, just get the cheapest shimano disc you can find, if you want it for mountain biking, are worried of disc heating up and can afford it, then get a more expensive one with cooling fins and specific metals for that.

Depending on what you do with the bike is what should determine the size of the rotors, if your rear disc is working fine and doing it's job, there is no need to get a biggest rotor. If you want more stopping power or are having problem with them overheating, then get a bigger rotor on the rear.

There is nothing to say you **shouldn't** have different size rotors front and rear.

When you're getting a new disc rotor though, you need to check the disc width is compatible with your brake. If you have a Shimano brake, there are [wide and narrow calipers](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com/2.0?acid=C-461&cid=C-460).
Narrow, two-piece disc rotors are incompatible with wide calipers, so this is something you need to take into account when buying a new disc rotor from Shimano or a third party.

Comment: Thanks. So any Shimano disc will fit any Shimano calipers?

Comment: Correct, the only difference is size of disc and materials of disc. Cost and performance is the main things that tell them apart.

Comment: @abdnChap those two last comments should be edited-in, because they improve and clarify the answer.

Comment: The cheapest shimano rotors are meant only to be used with resin pads. If you run sintered pads, even on a commuter, it's probably better to go for rotors to match